# Series of dependent terms.

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I have the series in the following form:
$$x + x(1-y) + x(1-x(1-y)) + x[1-x(1-x(1-y))]\cdots  $$
The expansion is very triangly :
$$x\\+x-xy\\+x-x^2+x^2y\\+x-x^2+x^3-x^3y\\+x-x^2+x^3-x^4+x^4y\\\cdots$$
This series will go on an arbitrary amount of steps.  The point here is that each term is $x(1-P)$ where $P$ is the single term that came right before.  Using this idea and setting $P$ appropriately in each loop, a programmed loop in c++ was very easy to write.

Whats this kind of series called? How would I get it into a summation form?

So far what I have is: 
$$x + \sum_{I=1}\Bigg[x+\Big[\sum_{n=2}^{I}(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}\Big]+(-x)^{I}y\Bigg]$$
Which would expand into the expansion above properly. Is this correct? **Please note that the inside summation is meant to be zero when I = 1**.  I know this converges on $\frac{x}{y}$ from the program I wrote, but I cant seem to remember the associated math.

This whole thing looks familiar, I feel like I have seen it before but I cant quite place it.  If possible, please include a term or name I can look up to learn more.

Comment: "triangly" is a nice word! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may define a recurrence as $$a_n = x(1 - a_{n-1}), \quad a_0 = y.$$  Note that this would give you the initial term as $y$, not $x$, as you have written, but that is okay since it only affects one term.

Next, suppose there is a related recurrence $b_n = a_n - k$ for all $n \ge 0$ for some constant $k$ that depends on $x, y$ in such a way that $\{b_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ is a geometric sequence.  Therefore, $$b_n + k = x(1 - (b_{n-1} + k)) = x(1-k) - xb_{n-1},$$ or $$b_n = x(1-k) - k - xb_{n-1}.$$  To eliminate the constant term, we thus require $$x(1-k)-k = 0,$$ or $$k = \frac{x}{x+1}.$$  Consequently, $$b_n = a_n - \frac{x}{x+1}$$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $-x$ and initial term $$b_0 = a_0 - \frac{x}{x+1} = y - \frac{x}{x+1}.$$  Hence  $$\sum_{n = 0}^{m-1} a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} b_n + \frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{mx}{x+1} + \left(y - \frac{x}{x+1}\right) \frac{(-x)^m - 1}{(-x) - 1}. $$  To get your sum where the initial term is $x$ instead of $y$, simply subtract $y$ and add $x$ from the above expression.

For a computational example, suppose we wish to sum $a_n$ from $n = 0$ to $5$ with $x = 3$ and $y = 1/5$.  The result with the formula above would be $523/5$, with $m = 6$.  The individual terms are $$\left\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{12}{5},-\frac{21}{5},\frac{78}{5},-\frac{219}{5},\frac{672}{5}\right\},$$ the sum of which is indeed $523/5$.

Comment: The first term doesn't matter? I disagree.  Your math is got me in the right direction though thank. Ill look more into the ideas of recurrence relations and learn more.